# No service for type 'Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceManifest' has been registered

Tags: c#, iis-express, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I am creating a simple MVC application in VisualStudio 2015 Preview. The code is building, but when I try to run the application, I get the following error:

```
 System.InvalidOperationException
 No service for type 'Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceManifest' has been registered.

 at Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)


 at Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService<T>(IServiceProvider provider)


 at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.HostingServices.Import(IServiceProvider fallbackProvider)


 at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.HostingServices.Create(IServiceProvider fallbackServices, IConfiguration configuration)


 at Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.KlrHttpApplication.ApplicationStart(IHttpApplication application)


 at Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.HttpApplicationBase.InvokeApplicationStart(IHttpApplication application)

.NET Framework version 4.0.30319.0   |   Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS version 1.0.0-beta2-10855   |   IIS version 8.5.9748.0 (fbl_srv2_iis_dev(hseiler).131204-1218)   |   Need help?
```

In my project.json file I have the following dependencies listed

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta2"

},
```

In my StartUp.cs I have the following code

```
public class Startup
{

    public void configureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMvc();

    }
}
```

Please let me know if any other information is required. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `configureServices` to `ConfigureServices`